# How to get the train and test data for each fold in kfold cross validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

How can I access the train and test data for each fold in cross validation? I would like to save these in .csv files. I tried using the `split` function which generates the indices but it returns a generator object, not the indices.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, KFold
import numpy as np
X, y = np.ones((50, 1)), np.hstack(([0] * 45, [1] * 5))
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3)
x = skf.split(X, y, groups)
x

Output:
<generator object _BaseKFold.split at 0x7ff195979580>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StratifiedKFold` returns a generator, therefore you it to iterate over it as follows:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
     X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
     y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel so silly for not thinking of this. I had to use it as `X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]` else I was getting the error `Key Error: None of [Int64Index…] dtype='int64] are in the columns`

Comment: Can you please tell me how I could save each train test split as well?

Comment: Indeed I assume that `X` was a `numpy` array. if `X` is a `DataFrame`, iloc is the way to go. Concerning your question you can perform the iloc to select the data then a `X_train.to_csv(...)` to store it.